# Visualisations for the Decision Surface of Probabilties

Tags: data-visualization

Say that I learned a function f(x) and its range lies in 0 - 1. I have only two features in my input space. Other than overlaying a probability map on a cartesian plane, how do I visualize/interpret the probabilistic behaviour of my classifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, the only other reasonable possibility I can imagine are [partial dependence plots](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.6392.pdf).

> [...] a tool for visualizing the model estimated by any supervised
>   learning algorithm.  Classical partial dependence plots (PDPs) help
>   visualize the average partial relationship between the predicted
>   response and one or more features.  In the presence of substantial
>   interaction effects, the partial response relationship can be
>   heterogeneous.  Thus, an average curve,  such  as  the  PDP,  can 
>   obfuscate  the  complexity  of  the  modeled relationship.
>   Accordingly, ICE plots redefine the partial dependence plot by
>   graphing the functional relationship between the predicted response
>   and the feature for individual observations.

Basically it plots the mean expected response of your model given inputs partial variation (e.g. a curve is plotted with the mean response versus values of one feature, that's why it's partial).

---

But with only two dimensions plotting the actual probability surface sounds more fun.

Comment: yeah, those 2 are the only i can think of. thx

Comment: @sponge_knight I'm curious why you would accept the answer (in effect indicating the answer solved your problem) but not also upvote it (indicating the answer was useful). It would seem odd to suggest an answer solved your problem without also being useful. You're free to vote as you see fit but it seems an odd signal to send to an answerer. What should they interpret this to mean?

Comment: yea, you're right! upvoted!